# User Document ID is the same as User ID in Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I try to store users inside collection in Firestore as documents and want to make every User ID is same as Document ID..
I tried but it still gives me another ID for the user:

```
Future<void> userSetupDone() async {
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc();

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
String? uid = docUser.id;
// String? uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString();
String? email = auth.currentUser?.email.toString();
String? phone = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber.toString();
String? displayName = auth.currentUser?.displayName.toString();

users.add({'Uid': uid, "Email": email, "Phone": phone, "Name": displayName});
return;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update uid immediately after adding data to the database. Because you can not get id before adding that data from the Firestore Database.

You will get it by following code:

```
 Future<void> userSetupDone() async {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc();
    
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    String? email = auth.currentUser?.email.toString();
    String? phone = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber.toString();
    String? displayName = auth.currentUser?.displayName.toString();
    
    DocumentReference reference= await users.add({'Uid': '', "Email": email, "Phone": phone, "Name": displayName});
    await reference.update({"Uid": reference.id});
    return;
}
```

Comment: While this solution does work it implies an unnecessary write operation that has a cost. Actually you can generate a Document id before creating the corresponding document to Firestore, see my answer.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, I see your answer will work ONLY with an auto-generated ID of the document. But this will work with all scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The "scenario" (i.e. requirement) of the OP is "I want to create a document with an autogenerated ID and save this ID in the document itself". Your answer fulfills the OP's requirements but it implies **two writes** to Firestore while there is a solution to do the same with only one write.

Answer (score 5):

By calling the [`add()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) method in

```
users.add({'Uid': uid, "Email": email, "Phone": phone, "Name": displayName});
return;
}
```

you actually create a new document **with an auto-generated ID** and therefore its ID is different from the one you got via `String? uid = docUser.id;`.

So you need to use the [`set()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) method on the `DocumentReference` you created (i.e. `docUser`), as follows:

```
await docUser.set({'Uid': uid, "Email": email, "Phone": phone, "Name": displayName});
```

Comment: That's the simplest and cheapest way to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> userSetupDone() async {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    String? docId = users.id;
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(docId);
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String? uid = docUser.id;
    String? email = auth.currentUser?.email.toString();
    String? phone = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber.toString();
    String? displayName = auth.currentUser?.displayName.toString();
    users.add({'Uid': uid, "Email": email, "Phone": phone, "Name": displayName});
return;}
```

try this

Comment: it printed: "Users" in UiD